# Portable Class Library - you must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

We have a Portable Class Library targeting 4.0.  A WPF application references this which is a standard .NET 4.0 app.

The PCL references the System.Net.NetworkCredential class.

When we build the .NET 4.0 app we get an error:

```
The type 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
```

Several posts say to install KB2468871.  That doesn't apply/change things.

If we add an assembly reference to "System.Net 4.0.0.0" in the app then the error changes:

```
Reference to type 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Net.dll', but it could not be found...
```

Of course NetworkCredential is not in System.Net, it is in the System assembly.

If I retarget to 4.5 everything works, but we need to use 4.0.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I can repro this with VS2013 and .NET 4.5.1.  You can report this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Created bug report 808382 with simplest of samples for download.  Would still be good if people have workarounds. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808382/portable-class-library-unusable-you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-system-net-version-2-0-5-0

Answer (score 1):

KB2468871 enables portable libraries to run on 4.0, it does not enable them to build in Visual Studio.

The first error should go away if you add a reference to System.Net, 4.0.0.0. If it does not, then you're machine is missing a required patch.

If are using:

**Visual Studio 2010**

You need to install Portable Library Tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/. This will install a patch that will make this work.

**Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013**

This should work out of the box, if not, then you install is likely in an incomplete state. Try repairing your installation.